# Search for a file using a wildcard

Tags: python, file, wildcard

I want get a list of filenames with a search pattern with a wildcard. Like:

```
getFilenames.py c:\PathToFolder\*
getFilenames.py c:\PathToFolder\FileType*.txt
getFilenames.py c:\PathToFolder\FileTypeA.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

*Note*: 
If the directory contains files starting with `.` they won’t be matched by default. For example, consider a directory containing `card.gif` and `.card.gif`:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('.c*')
['.card.gif']
```

This comes straight from here: http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html

Comment: As Donald Miner points out in the other answer, this isn't quite correct depending upon the shell being used.

Answer (score 22):

`glob` is useful if you are doing this in within python, however, your shell may not be passing in the `*` (I'm not familiar with the windows shell).

For example, when I do the following:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

On my shell, I type:

```
$ python test.py *.jpg
```

I get this:

```
['test.py', 'test.jpg', 'wasp.jpg']
```

Notice that `argv` does not contain `"*.jpg"`

The important lesson here is that *most shells will expand the asterisk at the shell*, before it is passed to your application.

In this case, to get the list of files, I would just do `sys.argv[1:]`. Alternatively, you could escape the `*`, so that python sees the literal `*`. Then, you can use the `glob` module.

```
$ getFileNames.py "*.jpg"
```

or

```
$ getFileNames.py \*.jpg
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're on Python 3.5+, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)'s [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) instead of the `glob` module alone.

Getting all files in a directory looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path("/path/to/directory").glob("*"):
    print(path)
```

Or, to *just* get a list of all `.txt` files in a directory, you could do this:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path("/path/to/directory").glob("*.txt"):
    print(path)
```

Finally, you can search recursively (i.e., to find all `.txt` files in your target directory *and* all subdirectories) using a wildcard directory:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path("/path/to/directory").glob("**/*.txt"):
    print(path)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from glob import glob
import sys

files = glob(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this to the previous because I found this very useful when you want your scripts to work on multiple shell and with multiple parameters using `*`.

If you want something that works on every shells, you can do the following (still using `glob`):

```
>>> import glob
>>> from functools import reduce # if using python 3+
>>> reduce(lambda r, x: r + glob.glob(x), sys.argv[1:], [])
```

Note that it can produce duplicate (if you have a `test` file and you give `t*` and `te*`), but you can simply remove them using a `set`:

```
>>> set(reduce(lambda r, x: r + glob.glob(x), sys.argv[1:], []))
```