# What replaces the asterisk in Python?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to copy csvs into postgres. all my csvs will always have the same suffix, such as competitors or customers, along with a unique number each time i generate them. therefore I want a python script that can run to use COPY and I can just have 'dir/customers*.csv'

is there an easy way to do this, does asterisk exist as some other character in python?

Thanks in advance!

Ok so what I currently have is a geoprocessing model in ArcGIS that will generate a bunch of CSVs into C:\Data\Sheltered BLPUs\CSVs such as competitors and customers, but attaches a unique ID for each location onto the end of the filename e.g. customers17.csv. I then want a python script to copy all of these into postgres. All the tables exist as 'customers' or 'competitors' - this is what I wanted to write:

`cur.execute("COPY competitors FROM 'C:/Data/Sheltered BLPUs/CSVs/competitors*.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;")`

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348753/python-search-file-using-wildcard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import glob
print glob.glob('dir/customers*.csv')
```

Comment: ok thanks - but what else do i need to do to get this into postgres? i want to copy all of my csvs into matching tables in postgres, such as customers*.csv into customers table, next line is competitors*.csv into competitors, etc.

Comment: thats a different question.... this answers the question you posed. i dont understand what you want to do with postgres ...

Comment: ok well thanks, i've edited the answer to say more about what i mean. should i just raise this in another question?