# Move shapefile from one folder to another using python

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I'm working with shapefiles and using the ArcPy library. My script is creating a new shapefile based on a join and I want to know how to move the newly joined-shapefile from the environment location to a new folder. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1: use ArcPy to call [Copy_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000051000000) followed by [Delete_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0017/001700000052000000.htm).

Option #2: use Python to move the shapefile. A shapefile is just a group of files with the same base name but different extensions (.shp, .shx, etc.). Try [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348753/python-search-file-using-wildcard) to get the files that are part of the shapefile, then [use Python to move the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. I did not know the name of the tool to move files.