# Loading data from text file from only a part of the file name

Tags: python

I have a lot of data in different text files. Each file name contains a word that is chosen by me, but they also include a lot of "gibberish". So for example I have a text file called `datapoints-(my chosen name)-12iu8w9e8v09wr-140-ad92-dw9`

So the `datapoints` string is in all text files, the `(my chosen name)` is what I define and know how to extract in my code, but the last bit is random. And I don't want to go and delete that part in every text file I have, that would be a bit time consuming.

I just want to load these text files, but I'm unsure of how to target each file without using the "gibberish" in the end. I just want to say something like: "load file that includes (my chosen name)" and then not worry about the rest.

Comment: Use regular expressions to target the random string bit. The Python re library should help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I would search for the files in the directory using a wild card for the random part of the file name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348753/search-for-a-file-using-a-wildcard - loop through the list of files and read and edit the sting in each file using regular expressions to locate the random string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this returns a list of all your files using the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

```
import glob
your_words = ['word1', 'word2']
files = []
# find files matching 'datapoint-your words-*.txt'
for word in your_words:
    # The * is a wildcard, your words are filled in the {}. one by one
    files.extend(glob.glob('datapoint-{}-*.txt'.format(word)))

print files
```