# Passing string to subprocess.run seems to encase it in single quotes negating a wildcard search?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a set of directories on my machine related to PCI devices (GPUs). Within these directories are various `hwmon` interfaces. I am attempting to `find` the specific path for each PCI device by running the command, for example,

```
$ find /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/hwmon/hwmon* -maxdepth 0
```

Here the wildcard will match the single directory located under `.../hwmon/` for each PCI device. The above command outputs the following in my terminal

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/hwmon/hwmon2
```

I am attempting to automate this process in python with `subprocess.run`

```
subprocess.run('find', gpu_pci_device_path + '/hwmon/hwmon*', '-maxdepth', '0', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

Here I have already located (what I have termed) the PCI device path for each GPU in the variable `gpu_pci_device_path`. Then I am build the rest of the wildcard path to pass to `find`.

Though it seems `subprocess` is encasing the path I have built in single quotes based on the error it produces

```
find: ‘/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/hwmon/hwmon*’: No such file or directory
```

Thus it is negating my wildcard expression during `find`. **How can I supply this wildcard expression to `find` during the call to `subprocess.run`?**

My evidence that the encasing is happening and the wildcard is negated is from the output of the command

```
$ find '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/hwmon/hwmon*' -maxdepth 0
find: ‘/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/hwmon/hwmon*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That wildcard would normally be expanded by the shell before it's passed to `find`, but you're running this (implicitly) with `shell=False`, so that doesn't happen. You could use `shell=True`, but then `find` isn't actually doing anything other than printing the names it gets from the shell, which seems pointless. And the output is potentially ambiguous (if the filenames contain weird characters). Why not do it directly in Python with [`glob.glob` or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348753/search-for-a-file-using-a-wildcard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Easy (Shell-Free) Answer

Using `shell=True` is bad practice, and you have no reason to do so here: Python can perform globbing itself with standard-library functionality.

```
subprocess.run((['find'] + 
                glob.glob(gpu_pci_device_path + '/hwmon/hwmon*') +
                ['-maxdepth', '0']),
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

This is not *quite* like real shell behavior: If no paths match, this will simply make the first argument to `find` be `-maxdepth`, which a shell would only do if the non-default `nullglob` option were set. To fix that, see below.

---

#### The Longer (Shell-Compatible) Answer

To get a closer emulation of the shell's behavior, we might add a wrapper around `glob.glob()` that makes default semantics more POSIX-y, and to support bash's `failglob` and `nullglob` options (which in bash can be enabled with `shopt`) to tune behavior when no matching files are found, and `globstar` to make `**` optionally able to recurse:

```
import errno
import glob
import os
import subprocess

def glob_or_literal(expression, nullglob=False, failglob=False, globstar=False):
    literal_result = glob.glob(expression, recursive=globstar)
    if literal_result or nullglob:
        return literal_result
    if failglob:
        raise FileNotFoundError(errno.ENOENT, os.strerr(errno.ENOENT), expression)
    return [expression]

subprocess.run((['find'] + 
                glob_or_literal(gpu_pci_device_path + '/hwmon/hwmon*') +
                ['-maxdepth', '0']),
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
```

...in which case, if no `hwmon` directory exists, you'll get the literal glob expression passed to `find` to let it write an appropriately useful error message (just like POSIX-family shells do by default), unless you set the `nullglob` option (instructing the function, or a shell, to make a non-matching glob not expand to any arguments -- which may have unwanted behavior, like GNU `find` deciding to start the search in the current directory), or the `failglob` option (which makes the shell, or in this case the `glob_or_literal` Python function, abort before starting `find` at all).